# SBT in a non-Ivy environment

Tags: scala, sbt

I work for a java shop and we use JFROG artifactory.

I am trying to use Scala and SBT, but I see everyone doing Scala projects prefers to use maven with scala plugin.

I want to know what settings, configuration, I need to do in a SBT project so that it disables IVY altogether and my builds interact with the JFROG server just like maven would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. it is documented here

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Using-Sonatype.html